# Customizing the Widget content markup

Tags: customization, widgets, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create panels for the sidebar widgets, and I can set the container markup for the widget, as well as the markup for the panel header, but I cannot provide the markup for the panel content. I have this so far:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Right Sidebar'),
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-default">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3></div>'
));
```

bootstrap panels need to look like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I add the '<div class="panel-body">###</div>' to each widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

- opening `<div class="panel-body">` to the end of `after_title`
- closing `</div>` to the start of `after_widget`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is somewhat older, but I thought I would point out that the previous answer only works if there is always a title.

If you want to make sure that only the content of the widget gets wrapped in a `panel-body` class, you might want to try something like this:

```
function my_widget_content_wrap($content) {
    $content = '<div class="panel-body">'.$content.'</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'my_widget_content_wrap');
```